# Driving License required for travelling to France from UK

Tags: france, uk, driving, driving-licenses

What driving license is required for driving in France from UK? Is it paper, card or both? The [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/driving-abroad) site says:

> You can use your Great Britain (GB) or Northern Ireland driving
>   licence in all European Union (EU) or European Economic Area (EEA)
>   countries

whereas the [RAC page](http://www.rac.co.uk/travel/driving-abroad/countries/france/) says:

> A valid, full UK driving licence - both the photo card and paper counterpart

I would take both but I can only find my card license at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theoretically you need both, because the plastic one is not valid without the paper counterpart (at least this is written on the paper counterpart). Having said that, I would be really surprised if the French actually bothered to look at the paper one -- I haven't checked it myself though.

Comment: Note that the UK has now abandoned the paper counterpart in favor of an online system. This answer was presumablly correct at time of writing but not anymore.